# ios load first page every time the app is opened

Tags: ios, iphone

is there anyway to make the app load the first page every time it's opened?

It would be nice if some one can help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enter in info.plist app key "Application does not run in background" and put for it value YES

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the AppDelegate

Just add code that reloads to the first page.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to call the first page from the delegate, my first page is the first page on my tab bar

Answer (score 0):

In you app delegate, connect your tabBar to an iVar, and do this:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.mayTabBar.selectedIndex=0;
}
```

This will switch to the first (leftmost) item in the tabBar.